# Copy collections index c# mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, indexing

Every month I need to update my mongo collections, I delete my old collections and then create collections with the same indexes manually in the same database. Then I run a program which inserts the information from txt files to the collections.
The reason I do this is because the collections are big and deleting all documents takes too much time, droping them is much faster.

Since there are many collections with different indexes I wish to do this programmatically. 
Is there a way to do this programmatically in C#?

1. Copy indexes in collection into a list
2. Drop collection
3. Create colection with the indexes in the list and the same name

Some of these collections have 2DSPHERE indexes.

This is my code so far, but i got stuck in the last part of creating the indexes from the list:

```
//connecting to mongo
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://" + MongoUser + ":" + MongoPass + "@" + MongoURL);    
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> myCollection = client.GetDatabase("DatabaseName").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("CollectionName");

//Save indexes into a list before drop
List<BsonDocument> indexList = myCollection.Indexes.List().ToList();

//Drop and recreate         
client.GetDatabase("DatabaseName").DropCollection("CollectionName")
client.GetDatabase("DatabaseName").CreateCollection("CollectionName");

// Get new created collection
myCollection = client.GetDatabase("DatabaseName").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("CollectionName");

foreach (BsonDocument doc in indexList )
{
   //Not working
    myCollection.Indexes.CreateOne(doc);
}
```

Comment: Alright then. It's a `List` of BsonDocuments. Pretty sure there is a thing to `CreateIndex` which will take a BsonDocument as it's argument. So if it's a `List`, then your "iterate" the list and pass each thing to the method. Also if "inserting" and not "upserting", it's considerably faster to do the index creation *after* all the insertions. Otherwise every insert is writing to both collection and index. Honestly though if you are simply cleaning a set of collections, just use a `mongodump` and `mongorestore` combination from a dump of the empty collections ( but indexed of course )

Comment: This is part of an entire proccess made in C# so I need to do this way. 
About the function. There is a function that creates index from BsonDocument but I get a message saying it's obsolete and should use CreateIndexModel instead. The function is also not workung, it's  throwing an MongoCommandException with a message "bad index key pattern"